# Looping Through a ForEach Multidimentional array 5 times only

Tags: php, joomla, multidimensional-array

I have a simple problem which I simply can't find the answer too. I have a multi-dimentional array coming from my Joomla which currently shows all the blog articles on my website. I only want to show the most recent 5.

Here's the code:

```
<?php 
foreach($list as $item) { 
?>

<li>
    <a href="<?php echo $item->link; ?>" class="latestnews<?php echo $params->get('moduleclass_sfx'); ?>">
        <?php echo $item->text; ?></a>
</li>



}
?>
```

I've seen a few similar posts but none of them seem to do what I'm looking for. Hopefully a simple one to the trained eye. Please help me on my day off! :-)

Newbie :-(

Answer (score 3):

You can use `array_slice()` to slice off the first 5, assuming they are ordered from newest to oldest.

```
<?php 
foreach(array_slice($list, 0, 5) as $item) { 
?>
```

If they are ordered the opposite way, use `array_slice($list, -5)`.

Comment: Dear Alex, thanks sooo much, I would never of found that answer. That's made my day. It works a treat! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Either you use `array_slice()` to get only the part of the array that you need, or you can use  a counter in your loop and [`break`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.break.php) when you reach you desired number.

As `array_slice()` is displayed in another answer, I'll just give you an example using a counter and break:

```
<?php 
$i = 0;
foreach($list as $item) {

if ($i > 4)
  break;

$i++;
?>

<li>
    <a href="<?php echo $item->link; ?>" class="latestnews<?php echo $params->get('moduleclass_sfx'); ?>">
        <?php echo $item->text; ?></a>
</li>

<? } ?>
```